# Null pointers since upgrading to Hibernate 5.4.3

Tags: hibernate

I've rarely had to touch the HibernateCrudServiceDAO class of a webapp I manage - it's always just worked.  This changed yesterday after upgrading from Hibernate 5.1.0 to 5.4.3.

IntelliJ correctly earmarked a deprecated Hibernate class and method: org.hibernate.Query and org.hibernate.query.Query.setFlushMode().  These I changed to org.hibernate.query.Query and setHibernateFlushMode(), respectively.  However, the method below is now generating a null pointer exception.

It seems that something has changed 'under the hood' of Hibernate since 5.1.0, and some changes may now need to be made in my HibernateCrudServiceDAO class to accommodate this.

Your help and insights would be much appreciated.

```
**HibernateCrudServiceDAO method** 

    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    public <T> T findUniqueWithNamedQuery(String queryName, Map<String, Object> params){
        Set<Entry<String, Object>> rawParameters = params.entrySet();
        Query query = session.getNamedQuery(queryName); 

        for(Entry<String, Object> entry : rawParameters){
            query.setParameter(entry.getKey(), entry.getValue());
        } 

        return (T) query.setHibernateFlushMode(FlushMode.MANUAL).uniqueResult();
    }


**Line which calls the above** 

    User user = crudService.findUniqueWithNamedQuery(User.BY_CREDENTIALS, QueryParameters.with("userName", userName).and("password", digest).parameters());


**The named query** 

    @NamedQuery(name = User.BY_CREDENTIALS, query = "Select u from User as u where u.userName = :userName and u.password = :password")
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On further investigation, it turns out that the problem is in the tapestry-hibernate module of Apache Tapestry.  Evidently the changes that occurred in Hibernate 5.2 broke something in tapestry-hibernate, resulting in certain methods returning null Query objects.

The workaround until this module gets fixed: change affected method calls from session.blah() to session.getSession().blah().

Tapestry ticket lodged: https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/TAP5-2754